# Fitting data on a Bessel function (of 2nd kind) with scipy

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have data that looks like a Bessel function of second kind (and arguably should be described by one of these functions).

I've been trying to do so using the scipy optimize toolbox following the documentation example but without success so far: I get the following error message

```
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

I'd say that the divergence in 0 is the cause of the problem.

By the way, I'm trying to fit two parameter, the index of the Bessel function and a scale factor in the varialbe, a and b in K<sub>a</sub>(bx). Is it a problem to try to fit on a discrete space (a takes value in the natural integers).

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
from scipy.special import yn #importing the Bessel functions
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(var, a, b):
    return yn(b*var,a)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y) # x and y are my data points
```

Comment: what do your data look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're passing to `yn` the arguments in the wrong order, it should be `yn(a,b*var)` instead of `yn(b*var,a)`. Likely it was this mistake leading to the function `yn` blowing up to `inf`.

As a second point, as you suspected, `scipy` will truncate your `a` to a float when you call `yn`, raising a `RuntimeWarning`. You're better off optimizing only with respect to your scaling variable `b`, and then investigate different values for the integer order `a`. You can do that either by hand, or in a loop.

I'll discuss some converge issues starting with an example, fitting `sin(x)/2` with `yn(1,x)` on `[1,2*pi]`.

```
from scipy.special import yn
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from numpy import sin,linspace,pi

a=1#choose the order a here!
func = lambda var,b : yn(a,b*var)

x=linspace(1,2*pi,100)
y=sin(x)/2.#we fit this as an example
[b], pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y) # x and y are my data points
print b
```

[image]

If you now change your domain to `x=linspace(0,2*pi,100)[1:]`, it happens that `curve_fit` will not converge. This is because in the part of the domain close to zero the optimization algorithm will try to squeeze `yn` towards the axis. This leads to large values of `b`, that in turn result in a strongly oscillatory behaviour of the function (try `plot(x,yn(a,10*x))`) up to a discretization limit (try `plot(x,yn(a,10*x))`) where things get even worse.

The moral is that if your data is close to zero for low `x`, you should start fitting a bit far away from zero to get decent convergence.

As a side note, usually `Ka(x)` refers to the MODIFIED Bessel function of the second kind, while `yn` is the Bessel function of the 2nd kind, more often referred to as `Ia(x)`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, really useful. I just checked the last point and yes, indeed the functions I'm interested are actually the kn(a,b*x).

Comment: Okay many thanks, I think that I made it work know (except for finding the right discrete index), I also had a huge scaling factor to add (10^7) to make the function converge, but it now looks like it fits the data ;)

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it worked out. What's the data about anyway? Does your problem have a radial symmetry of any sort?

Comment: It's not related to a wave pde (to my knowledge but should be described by similar equations). It's a numerical calculation of density of loops in statistical models at criticality (boundaries clusters of spins in the Ising model for instance). These thing are described by correlation functions in conformal field theory and usually obey to hypergeometric differential equation, hence the Bessel function I think.